# mount two network drives under different directories under /mnt

Tags: networking, mount, fstab

So far I have mounted a network drive under `/mnt` directly in `/etc/fstab` and it works well.

I have now a second network drive that I want to mount and I am getting into problems.

Let's say that the network drives have these address:

```
192.168.1.11/volume1/video
192.168.1.11/volume2/videos
```

So far (only 1 share) I used to mount it all under `/mnt` and that directory would contain all sub-directories of the original share.

Now I want to change the way this works so that `/mnt` has 2 sub-directories:

```
/mnt/volume1/video
/mnt/volume2/videos
```

But I can't. It won't mount to `volume1/video` because the folder does not exist.

If I create the two folders in `/mnt` while the first drive is mounted, the `volume1` and `volume2` directories are actually created into the original share drive

If I unmount everything, create the folders then try and mount to the newly created folders I get an error - and googling tells me it's because I need to have `/mnt` mounted before.

Can anybody help me understand what I should be doing?

thank you

Comment: What steps do you try exactly and what errors/unexpected behavior do you get exactly? Please include the exact commands you run and the outputs you get. And how does your fstab look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is the already existing entry in `/etc/fstab`. It holds the `/mnt` some kind of locked because it "knows" that at any time there will be a drive mounted to.

1. Remove (or comment out) the entry from `/etc/fstab` and reload `sudo mount -a` or reboot
2. Create the two folders

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /mnt/volume1/video
   sudo mkdir -p /mnt/volume2/videos
   ```

   `-p` creates the the necessary parent folders, too
3. Now add the according entries to `/etc/fstab`
4. You already should be able to test it now using `sudo mount` to mount manually.
5. Reboot to check if the `fstab` mounts automatically now.

Comment: This made it. What I think I did wrong was the original /mnt mounted - as you mentioned somehow it prevented the new mounts to work as intended.